# Vivado Webpack VS Design Edition

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado

Right now I am using Vivado design edition which I got for free with my diligent basys 3 FPGA.  I am currently looking to upgrade my card to Nexys Video which has a lot more features.  http://store.digilentinc.com/nexys-video-artix-7-fpga-trainer-board-for-multimedia-applications/

It says on their site "Design Edition licenses for Vivado are not yet available to purchase with the Nexys Video. We are working to get them in stock and hope to have them for sale soon.".  It also says "The Nexys Video is compatible with both ISE® and Vivado® toolchains. It is supported in the free WebPACK™ versions of these two tools so designs can be implemented at no additional cost." Which is good since I am not going to pay for a full vivado license since this is just a hobby.

I then looked at this comparison table between vivado design edition and webpack.  http://www.xilinx.com/products/design-tools/vivado/vivado-webpack.html

The webpack edition seems to do everything design edition does except that it only works with certain cards which is not a problem for me.  So why then would digilent need to offer design edition with the cards if webpack does everything for that particular card anyway.  What are the differences?

Comment: Webpack used to not be include Chipscope license, which is essential to any big design development IMHO. In fact, I find it strange it is included according to the table you link, I would not have expected Xilinx to change that. Also, Microblaze is not (or used not to) be included in the Webpack license, Zynq is however. SDK for the Microblaze is always free. So basically, you use to buy a license if you target is not supported, you needed chipscope or microblaze. Lots of small companies do with a single license, and use Webpack for the main development flow.

Comment: I have the node locked version for my basys 3.  It does not seem to have chip scope.  I use the integrated logic analyzer for debugging which seems to do the same thing

Comment: Also I think I saw somewhere that microblaze is now included with webpack.

Comment: The ILA is chipscope. Maybe they rebranded to remove the name, but an old designer knows what's what ;) You need (or used to) a license to generate a design with ILA core, but any free license can debug a FPGA with a chipscope core. Xilinx has a free microblaze system with limited functionality freely available since 2-3 years (I think called Microblaze MCS). But the "real" microblaze with high performances and external memory should still need a license, until proven otherwise!